# I've heard that some "break"s aren't bad practice. What about this one?

Tags: java, primes, break

I have often heard that using `break`s in Java is considered bad practice, but after reading some threads on Stack Overflow, I've seen otherwise. Many say that it is acceptable in certain cases.

I'm a little confused as to what is/isn't bad practice in this case.

For [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/): Problem 7, I've constructed the code below. The challenge was to find the 10001st prime.

```
int index = 2, count = 1, numPrime = 1;

while (true) {
    index++;

    if (isPrime(index)) {
        count = index;
        numPrime++;
    }

    if (numPrime >= 10001)
        break;
}

System.out.println(count);
```

This returns the correct answer (in 21ms), but am I overlooking a serious warning? It's 100% possible to create a while loop without a break, but I find that this is a little easier to follow.

Is the way I use the `break;` bad practice? I know that there's always a way around using one, but is it really that terrible here?

Many thanks

Justian

**EDIT**

Here's my isPrime() code. I might as well optimize this while I'm at it.

```
public static boolean isPrime(long num) {  
    if (num == 2)
        return true;

    if (num % 2 == 0 || num <= 0)
        return false;

    for (long i = 3; i * i <= num; i += 2)
        if (num % i == 0)
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: For future reference: http://tweakers.net/ext/f/JSTvlKvM7Xj8DCnEIU6wiIXG/full.png Don't shoot the gun too fast :P

Comment: My second terrible question in a row this week. Hopefully not all bad things come in threes.

Comment: BTW, you are skipping the prime number 2, in the above code.

Comment: @aepryus: I know it's not the 10001st prime, so why bother? It's just another number to parse ;). Sure it doesn't save much time, but it's not important in this case. If I were to construct a method asking for the nth prime, then it would be important.

Comment: I just hope I'm not slowly labeling myself as one of those messy Java programmers. I'm doing my best with what limited class instruction I have. Hopefully my C classes in college will help straighten me out.

Comment: You are counting primes.  This function wont stop until you find 10,001 primes.  If you skip 2, this function will return the 10,002nd prime.

Comment: @aepryus: I already mentioned that I receive the proper output - that was not the issue. Please review the code further. It's like saying `for (int i = 1; i <= 10001; i++) {` instead of the more common `for (int i = 0; i < 10001; i++) {`.

Comment: @Justian Meyer: That is a bad optimization IMHO. You're skipping the number which is fastest to check and at the same time making the code so tricky that you've confused several other people here. Try to avoid clever tricks - keep things simple.

Comment: FYI, you could speed up the code significantly by auto-skipping numbers divisible by 2 and 3. Increment index by 6 each run and test index+1 and index+5. Or just auto-skip even numbers.

And for the love of all that's holy, make sure that isPrime only tests against prime numbers less than or equal to sqrt(index).

Comment: @Thom Smith: I have tried skipping these numbers with little luck - my code just became too messy, but I know it's best. I will post my isPrime() code above. I only go to the square root.

Comment: You can make that run many orders of magnitude faster. Will post example.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In this case, it looks to me like it would be easier just to change the `while` condition:

```
while (numPrime < 10001) {
```

That's usually the case when a `while(true)` loop ends with

```
if (condition)
{
    break;
}
```

... although you need to check whether anything else in the body of the loop performs a `continue`.

Alternatively, you could restructure it slightly:

```
int current = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 10001; i++)
{
    current++;
    while (!isPrime(current))
    {
        current++;
    }
}
```

Then `current` will be the answer at the end.

I generally prefer a `for` loop over a while loop, when you're trying to do something a particular number of times. In this case the "something" is "find the next prime".

There are various bits of dogma in programming that I feel are taken too far - including "one exit point to a method" and "don't use break." Write code as readably as you can. If you look at some code and feel it's not blindingly obvious what's going on, try to work out other ways of structuring it. Sometimes that's a case of changing a loop; sometimes it's extracting a method; sometimes it's inverting some logic (deal with a negative branch first, possibly exiting early, and then handle the normal case).

Comment: I gave Jon this point because not only did he provide a nice `for` solution, but his explanation of good/bad practice was more definite than Andrzej's.

Comment: +1 for the same reason that Justian states.  (And maybe, just maybe, because I don't have the Populist badge yet... ;-)).  You're spot on about the dogmatic approach to those things, and I've never understood why some people miss the wood of increasing readability for the trees of conforming to The Process.

Comment: As noted in Adrzej's answer, a `while(true)` ending with a `break` fits a do/while construct better.

Answer (score 22):

I'm not sure that breaks in general are bad practice, but I think that this one is.

It's a bit silly because it's unnecessary.  Your `while (true) ... break` is entirely equivalent to:

```
while (numPrime < 10001) {
   ...
}
```

but much less intuitive.

Sticking with the canonical way to represent things means less computational overhead for your readers, makes your code easier to understand, thus easier to maintain and ultimately more robust.

Edit (in response to comment):  You're right that there's always a way around using one, but the rule (if you want one) is relatively simple: write whatever is most readable.  In the case you posted, this is not the most readable as the alternative I gave is the canonical way to represent this.  In some cases, for example looping though a collection until you find a specific candidate that matches, using `break` probably **is** the most fitting way to represent this pattern.

It would be difficult (and I woudl argue, futile) to try to come up with hard-and-fast rules about when to use `break` and when to pull out variables and use conditionals instead.  Often it's easy to tell what's the simplest option, but not always.  This is one of those examples where experience really counts - the more good/bad code you've read and wrote yourself, the bigger your personal library of good and bad examples, and the easier it will be for you to tell what the "best"* way to represent a given concept is.

*Of course it's subjective!

Comment: Absolutely. Not much gets on my goat more than `while(true)`

Comment: @Andrzej Doyle: I really just added it in example :/. Should have picked a better one.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't convey any information about what's being done in the loop.  Very occasionally it's valid, if something is meant to loop "forever", but even then you should usually have a `while(!shutdown)`-based flag instead.

Comment: I like to use `while (1+1+1 != 2)` or similar, just to confuse people.

Comment: @Justian: Hopefully the edit redeems my (admittedly excessive) upvotes to some extent.

Comment: Good answers to easy questions always get the most rep, lots of people understand the question and agree it's right :)

Comment: Not quite equivalent, as this way it requires a JMP to the start of the loop to evaluate the condition, whereas the break (or better, a do/while) does not.

Comment: @sje397: Fee fi fo fum, I smell the blood of premature optimisation...  (edit) I would gladly sacrifice **one** CPU instruction in order to make my source code more readable.

Comment: @sje397: In compiler output I've seen, they often put the condition of a 'while' loop at the end of the loop, and enter the loop by jumping to it.

Comment: @Andrzej Doyle - absolutely not. I'm looking at equivalence to the original code, readability, and the reason why someone's intuition might cause them to write this way. That's *exactly* what do/while is for. Not to mention, optimisations like that *are* appropriate when calculating large prime numbers :)

Comment: For equivalence I'd be happy with functional equivalence, rather than the resulting bytecode/machine code being identical.  And OK, I do take your point but in the **vast** majority of situations one opcode is going to be irrelevant.  If your program spends its entire life in the loop then you have a point, but I feel you ought to have qualified your comment to that extent.

Comment: It's still mostly the equivalence in readability and meaning that makes me think do/while is more appropriate here. He always does the code inside the loop once at least. He checks the condition at the end. That *is* do/while.

Comment: You're right and I happen to agree with your assessment, but I consider it relevant that do/while is an uncommon construct and developers are used to seeing the loop condition at the top of the loop rather than at the end.  Consequently I'd only use a do/while if there was a chance the condition could be false on the first iteration, otherwise the behaviour is identical.  You have a point that in the *abstract* `do/while` is more natural here, but in practice, I would consider a simple `while` to be the canonical representation.

Answer (score 2):

if you can get away without a break, then do it.

do

```
 while (numPrime < 10001) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

That is what do/while was invented for:

```
do {
//...
} while(numPrime < 10001);
```

It's the `while(true)` bit that I find bad practice, which of course leads to `break`.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of conditions when it makes sense to use a break. One is when you need to execute N.5 loops -- i.e., you'll execute the loop some number of times, but the last time through you'll always execute somewhere in the middle of the loop body. You *can* avoid using a break in this case, but doing so often obfuscates the code or results in duplication. For example:

```
while (true) {
    first part;
    if (finished) 
       break;
    second part;
}
```

can be turned into something like:

```
first part;
while (!finished) {
    second part;
    first part;
}
```

or:

```
while (!finished) {
    first part;
    if (!finished)
        second part;
}
```

Neither of these is necessarily a major improvement. Another circumstance under which a break can make sense is simply dealing with something like an error. For example, if you've been passed N files to process, it may make sense to break out of the loop if one of them fails to open. Nonetheless, when it's *at all reasonable*, it's clearly better to have the condition under which you'll exit from the loop explicitly stated in the loop's condition.

Comment: The catch to your second example is that "first part" is now written twice. If you can push it all into a function that is simply called twice, that's not such a bad thing, but if not, well, any time you have the same block of code twice, sooner or later somebody is going to make a change to one occurrence and not the other, and now you have a mess.

Answer (score 2):

Not hugely different than anything that has been said before, but from readablity, transparent logic stand point I would recommend

```
long i,primes=0;
for (i=2;primes<10001;i++) {
    if (isPrime(i))
        primes++;
}
```

i is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one condition under which a loop can exit, and there isn't a whole lot of code that needs to run before checking the condition, and there isn't a whole lot of code that needs to run after checking the condition, put the condition in the loop.

I do think there are certainly uses for a "do{}while(1);" loop.  Among them:

1. In the loop-continue case, the primary condition needs to have enough code run both before and after it is checked that putting the code in the condition itself would be awkward at best.

   The loop has multiple exit conditions, and the exit condition which would most logically sit at the top or bottom of the loop would require special code to execute which should not execute for other exit conditions.

Some people like to use flags to distinguish exit conditions.  I tend to view such flags as an effort to avoid the coding structures which in fact best embody the action of the program.

If one isn't too concerned about speed, one can avoid ever using any form of *goto*, premature-exit *return*, or for that matter using more than one *while*--and that with a simple condition.  Simply write one's entire program as a state machine:

```
void do_whatever(void)
{
  int current_state=1;
  do
  {
    next_state = 0;
    if (current_state == 1)
    {
      do_some_stuff();
      next_state = 2;
    }
    if (current_state == 2)
    {
      do_some_more_stuff();
      next_state = 3;
    }
    ...
    current_state = next_state;
  } while(current_state);
}
```

There are times such coding is useful (particularly if the "while" can be pulled out of the do_whatever() routine into a loop which runs several similarly-coded routines "simultaneously").  And it's never necessary to use anything like a "goto".  But for readability, structured programming constructs are much nicer.

To my mind, to use a flag to exit a loop and then select one of several pieces of code to execute based upon the exit cause is to replace structured code with unstructured code.  If within a loop I write

```
  if (index >= numItems)
  {
    createNewItem(index);
    break;
  }
```

it's immediately (and locally) clear that the reason I'm creating a new item is because my index exceeded the number of items, and there's no need for me to redundantly test a condition.  If instead I loop until I've found something or run out of items, then I'll either have to redundantly test a condition after the loop or add a flag test to every loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, the example you gave is a bad one because you could easily move the test into the WHILE.

The cases where I use a break are when I have a loop where I must do some processing before I know that this is the last time through. For example:

```
while (true)
{
  String inLine=inStream.readLine();
  if (inLine.startsWith("End"))
    break;
  ... process line ...
}
```

This example is only slightly contrived: I often run into problems where I read some data from a file or other source, parse this data in some way, and only then know that I have reached the end of what I am interested in processing right now.

You could, of course, wrte a function that reads the line and does the parsing necessary, like:

```
while (!endOfInterestingData(inStream))
{
  ... process ...
}
```

But then you may have the problem that both the function and the body of the loop need access to the data read, and the function must return a boolean to control loop processing so it can't return the data, so the only way to make the data available to the loop body is to have the function throw it into some mutually-accessible field, which then obscures where the loop gets its data from.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is pretty fast:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long isqrt(unsigned long n) {
    // http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2715
    unsigned long a;
    for (a = 0; n >= (2*a)+1; n -= (2*a++) + 1);
    return a;
}

void nPrimes(const long N, long *const primes)
{
    unsigned long n, count, i, root;

    primes[0] = 2;
    count = 1;

    for (n = 3; count < N; n+=2) {

        root = isqrt(n);

        for (i = 0; primes[i] <= root; i++) {
            if ((n % primes[i]) == 0) goto notPrime;
        }
/*      printf("Prime #%lu is: %lu\n", count+1, n);*/
        primes[count++] = n;

        notPrime: ;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    long N;

    if (argc > 1) {
        N = atoi(argv[1]);
    } else {
        N = 10001;
    }

    long primes[N];

    nPrimes(N, primes);

    printf("Prime #%lu is: %lu\n", N, primes[N-1]);
}
```

Notes:

- isqrt(n) is floor(sqrt(n)). This avoids floating-point operations, which we don't need anyway. Algorithm from http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2715.
- nPrimes keeps a list of the primes. This allows you to test only prime divisors, which cuts out the vast majority of those costly mod operations.
- Even the primes are only tested up to isqrt(n).
- That's an ugly goto, but C doesn't have named continues, and a flag variable would have been a complete waste of time.
- The primes array is initialized with 2, and it only checks odd numbers from 3. Eliminating multiples of 3 is similarly doable, but not of trivial complexity.
- The isqrt call could be eliminated by keeping a table of squares of primes. This is almost certainly overkill, but you can if you want to.
- On my not-new machine, this runs in the blink of an eye.

Comment: I will run some speed tests with my method against yours and post the results shortly, if not some time tomorrow. ... On second thought, it will most likely come tomorrow, as I have to translate this into Java.