# Should I avoid do/while and favour while?

Tags: language-agnostic

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Test loops at the top or bottom? (while vs. do while)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224059/test-loops-at-the-top-or-bottom-while-vs-do-while)
>   [While vs. Do While](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390605/while-vs-do-while)

In discussions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373305/ive-heard-that-some-breaks-arent-bad-practice-what-about-this-one/3373326#3373326) it seems most people prefer `while` loops over `do/while` loops.

To me it seems `do/while` is a fundamental part of the language, and one that everyone should understand as easily as `while`. It may be less common, but avoiding it for this reason seems a bit like trying to talk in one syllable words.

Does avoiding `do/while` really help make my code more readable?